# Django rest framework AttributeError after GET request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

During a GET request, Django give me this error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `projectSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `ProjectTask` instance.
Original exception text was: 'ProjectTask' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

I'm pretty new to django and rest_framework, here's the code:

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.IntegerField()
```

serializers.py

```
class projectTaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectTask
        fields = ['description','status']

class projectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = projectTaskSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name','tasks']
```

views.py (I'm only mentioning the `get` function that is being called to avoid cluttering the question

```
def get(self, request):
    
    projects = ProjectTask.objects.all()
    serialized_projects = projectSerializer(projects,many = True)
    return Response({'projects' : serialized_projects.data})
```

Comment: Did you intend the code correctly?. The last `class Meta`?

Comment: Extra field in class Meta: of  projectSerializer ,

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM yup it's all indented properly, I edited the question to correct that

Comment: @FaisalNazik can you please elaborate?

Comment: You named your model as project and there is no tasks field in your project model

Comment: In
 class projectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = projectTaskSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project  # this model doesn't contains tasks field in your models 
        fields = ['name','tasks']

Comment: In class Meta of projectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) your model should be ProjectTask instead of Project

Comment: not sure that would work. I was trying to use the docs as reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships. I tried doing what the docs do for Album and Tracks models

Comment: @FaisalNazik turns out you were partially right, in the `get` function, I was getting the objects of `ProjectTask` instead of `Projects` which made it look for `name` inside `ProjectTask` instead of `Projects`